# way to find all application using a particular java version in Windows server

Tags: java, java-7, java-6

We have got two java versions on our server Java 1.6 and Java 1.7. Is there a way to find out what are the applications that are running on the machine that calls the version. Our requirement is to uninstall Java 1.6 but our concern is that it should not affect other application that uses the version so trying to find all the application that uses it.

Comment: If you do `java -version` in command line that is most likely the version it is running all java applications with... unless specified in a `bat` file and/or `direct path`

Answer (score 4):

You can try

```
ps aux | grep 'java'
```

if you're on Linux.

(**UPDATE:** OP subsequently clarified that we're on Windows here.)

That will show you which Java runtimes are running which apps. In the event that you can't tell (for example, the java in the ps output may be a symlink), just invoke that directly:

```
$ ps aux | grep 'java'
wwheeler        52434   0.0  0.7  8279924 112772 s000  S+    4:53PM   0:04.12 /usr/bin/java -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true -Xdock:name=Gradle -Xdock:icon=/usr/local/Cellar/gradle/2.12/libexec/media/gradle.icns -Dorg.gradle.appname=gradle -classpath /usr/local/Cellar/gradle/2.12/libexec/lib/gradle-launcher-2.12.jar org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain bootRun
wwheeler         9158   0.0  0.0  2434840    776 s002  S+    6:07PM   0:00.00 grep java
$ /usr/bin/java -version
java version "1.8.0_74"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_74-b02)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.74-b02, mixed mode)
```

Comment: unfortunately all servers are on windows

Comment: then use task manager and show the complete path to determine which is which

Comment: If you do java -version in command line that is most likely the version it is running all java applications with... unless specified in a bat file and/or direct path

Comment: @3kings Agreed, but it sounds like there's some question about whether that's actually the case. So I want to help him verify. (Well, if he were on Linux.)

Comment: @3kings we do have many processes running on the server. these are basically bat or exe files. they nay have a reference to the bin folder of the java1.6 we want to get rid of. so if there is a way to find all the running process and the java they call?

Answer (score 1):

No way to collect information about what application(s) use specific JRE instance. **You must do it manually**, because these information **exist inside your application's configuration**.

Supplement information, For finding JRE is running, Open your Task manager:
[image]

Open tab **Details**, find **java** process
[image]
Right click, then choose **Properties** from context menu:
[image]
You will see specific **Java JRE** is running.

Comment: thanks but what if there are other application that uses the java 1.6 version internally

Comment: I don't understand your comment, can you make your idea more clearly?

Comment: Ok, I already understand your idea. I will revise the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, when most of app’s, software, browsers, etc. are open/running,

Start --> System Information --> Software Environment --> Loaded Modules --> (Filter on Manufacturer and see Name, Version column
The above is for Laptop, same will hold good for server.